# Why is shared less secure than open when it comes to WEP?

Tags: network, windows, wep

According to this [post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c5aa823b-284a-4f7b-9cbc-a30f9b5e59f2/windows-8-wep-shared-key-resolution?forum=w8itpronetworking), Jeffrey Tippet (Microsoft employee) writes:

> **WEP can run in two modes: shared and open.  Despite the names, shared is actually less secure than open.**  Because of this, our
>   telemetry shows that that only 0.1% (and declining) of Windows 7 users
>   connect to these highly-insecure shared WEP networks.
>
> In order to simplify Windows, make it easier for people to pick more
>   secure defaults, and to enable us to focus on improving the wireless
>   networking that the other 99.9% of our customers use, we removed
>   shared WEP from Windows 8. Windows 8 continues to support open WEP. We
>   recommend that you configure your AP to use open WEP, as it's more
>   secure and more broadly-supported.

However, there isn't an explanation as to why shared is less secure than open. Why is this the case?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised anyone still uses WEP.  WEP is horribly insecure no matter which version you pick and has been since the late 90s.  I don't think I've seen an AP using WEP for years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared would send a plaintext query to authenticate clients which would be encrypted and returned. This left the key vulnerable to a known-plaintext attack.

Open would allow anyone to authenticate, but wouldn't pass plaintext around, making the key harder to guess.

[Here](http://wirelessnetworkssecurity.blogspot.com/2013/01/wep-open-key-vs-wep-shared-key.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy#Authentication) are links to more details.

Answer (score 1):

Shared authentication uses a challenge/response protocol to connect, and this makes it very susceptible to a dictionary attack offline. Using WEP in shared mode, You just need to enter a secret shared key to connect, and this is where the attack can be easily perpetrated. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, it's not necessarily. For example, if there are no clients, Open is less secure.

In general, shared is less secure because you can deauthenticate a client, which forces it to associate again. You then capture the shared key authentication handshake. In open mode, this handshake doesn't happen.